# Including Adsense Ads with PHP

Tags: php, adsense

Let's say I have a PHP page that has only one thing in it and that's an Adsense Ad. Let's say I have another PHP page which is the main page where all my content goes. I want this page to have three Adsense ads, so I just include the page that has the Adsense ad three times.

Would this affect website performance? Is it even allowable by Google to do this? The reason why I want to do this, is because sometimes I don't want an Ad displayed, instead I want a custom made advertisement.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you have tried yet.

Comment: @Daenarys I haven't tried anything because I want to see if a concept like this is allowable by Adsense. Since I am just including the ad of the page three times using PHP, then it should work.

Comment: Just make three adsense codes and include them in the situations you want them added.